# Various stack size for multiple recursive method invocations

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, jvm, stack-overflow

During experiments I've found very interesting issue related to Stack overflow error.
Take a look at this code:

Foo class:

```
public class Foo {

    private int i;

    public void doFoo() {
        i++;
        doBar();
    }

    public void doBar() {
        doFoo();
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void reset() {
         i = 0;
    }
}
```

App class:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        try {
            foo.doFoo();
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(foo.getI());
        }
    }
}
```

It's obvious that recursive invoking doFoo and doBar methods will cause stackOverflowError. But what value will have foo.i after this? I've tested it few times with default VM stack size - here it is what `System.out.println(foo.getI());` prints:

- 1st run: 4372
- 2nd run: 8364
- 3th run: 3381
- 4th run: 8406
- 5th run: 3485

Can you see it? Constantly running this app, i variable will be always ~4500 greater / smaller than previous run.

And what if we will increase stack size? when added `-Xss1m` parameter to VM args, here are the results:

- 1st run: 33364
- 2nd run: 38404
- 3th run: 33787
- 4th run: 38434
- 5th run: 33805

It's the same thing! i value is still ~4500 greater/smaller than previous run!

Hoever, when we change main method to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            foo.doFoo();
            foo.reset();
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(foo.getI());
        }
    }
```

we will have predictable results:

- 38398
- 80796
- 123194
- 165592
- 207990
- 250388
- 292786
- 335184
- 377582
- 419980

It may be due to more and more stack free space after JVM initialization. But, why there are ~4500 oscillations when program is invoked again and again?
PS. I'm running this app from Eclipse directly (if that matters).

====

Edit:

ok, so I can now see, that `foo.reset()` is never invoked, because Error is thrown before it. When `foo.dooFoo()` is swapped with `foo.reset()`, we have now constant result:

- 38394
- 42394
- 42394
- 42394
- 42394
- 42394
- 42394
- 42394
- 42394
- 42394

But, question why there are ~4500 oscillations when running program run by run, is still open.

==EDIT2

This issue is related only to running from Eclipse directly, without -Xint parameter. When program is started from command line, `java -cp . App`, i is more constant: +/- 5.

Comment: @venergiac added foo.reset()

Comment: intersting issue, but I cannot replicate the issue: 5704, 5712, 5708, 5712,5712, 5712, 5711. I'm using jdk 1.7

Comment: What happens if you run your original code with `-Xint` option? (this would test dependence on the JIT)

Comment: with -Xint same result. with -Xss2m: 11670, 11666, 11670, 11670

Comment: @MarkElliot yes, -Xint makes result more constant: 3380, 3387, 3377...

Comment: on my 64bit windows 7 JDK 1.7.0_21 build, i is around 5704 with a variation of +-5. You seem to have a 32 bit system on which you are trying and JDK6. Default values on 32 system for stack size is about 512k i think. try with -Xint to check if JITing is impacting your code. Its possible that frequent recursion is hitting JIT and its killing your code at random. Am sure with -Xint you would get a better consistency in value of i.Debugging in eclipse and check your code example in visualvm, there is heavy JIT work going on in the back.

Comment: @Nazgul I ran this app from cmd, and I can see, that this issue is related only to running from eclipse directly. And yes, adding -Xint caused that i is more constant now.

Comment: if you see the issue only from eclipse directly, then do check if you are using a JRE or a JDK as you default workbench runtime. Check whats selected in preferences > Java > installed JRE

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what's happening (and what your evidence shows) is that the methods are being called frequently enough that your code ends up being run through the JIT compiler. When that happens, I'd speculate that the optimization likely kicks in and recognizes that incrementing `i` on every execution of `doFoo` isn't necessary -- kind of like unrolling a loop.

I'm not totally sure why you see any variability, except that there may be a non-deterministic cost component for when the JIT kicks in, or that occasionally it kicks in off by a few frames sometimes.

Comment: I've tested it from cmd, and it seems like it's related to running from Eclipse directly - from cmd there are no oscillations.